# Android. Создание папки в корне SD

Tags: java, android

Необходимо создать папку в корне SD карты. Android API 21+.

В манифесте прописано:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Код:

```
private boolean isExistDir() {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + File.separator + "myDir");

        if (dir.exists())
            return true;
        if (dir.mkdirs())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Проверка на наличие SD (Возвращает true):

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Но при вызове `mkdirs()` получаю false. Папка не создается. Как создать папку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение совершенно случайно.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Почему не догадался до этого сразу:

Причина 1: Нагуглил штук 5-10 похожих вопросов, везде советовали указывать только "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAG".

Причина 2: Я искренне думал, что права на запись подразумевают права на чтение. Т.е. если разрешено только READ, то WRITE запрещено. Но! Если разрешено WRITE, то и READ пожалуйста.

Остается вопрос, почему не работало без "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE". Но думаю что это особенность API 21+.

Comment: Вообще, 19+. http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  "This permission is enforced starting in API level 19."